# Error when trying to install Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I been trying to install Ubuntu for my new laptop for ages now. Always getting the same error the very last second of the install.

Here is a screenshot and a the log of the install.

LOG : http://pastebin.com/sHr1x7C7
Screenshot: http://i40.tinypic.com/160vi88.jpg

Used the windows installer. Tried to reboot multiple times. But the OS is not showing up on the list on boot.

Comment: Off topic: http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the distrib is ubuntu, not ubunto.\
Secondly, I recommand you to use a live CD or a USB stick if you want to try the system, and if it works well and/or you like it, install the system using that same medium.

There are plenty of howto on the internet, so I won't explain here, but the principle is to reduce windows partition (or allocating a full hard drive for linux) and manage the partition scheme throw the installer.

Hope this helps, at least a little :-)

Comment: Thank you for you're answer. Been googling my self for 2 days and found to solution so i came here. Whoever down voted my question is a prick. This is the stuff which this website is for.

Thank you one more for the answer. I'll try to burn it straight away.

Answer (score 1):

First, it's ubuntu, not ubunto. From my google searches your problem is a pretty common one with no apparent solution. Burn the ISO to CD and install that way, it is the most reliable method. If you cannot do that, try the USB or netboot options, but the CD is the best way.